# crm 2011: How provide a frendly response after discarding a request in a plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Just as the title, how to provide a friendly feedback after discarding a request in a plugin?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only supported way is to use something like following:

```
throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Your message");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Putting your reply and Sxntk's reply together is a perfect answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to rollback the transaction you can handle the message in a field. After that in a javascript read that message and show it in the native crm div so you don't throw an exception.